# Cannot observe phoneNumber on firebase.User

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, mobx, mobx-react

I have created `firebase.User` observable as follows, and assign to the current user in `onAuthStateChanged` callback, and things work as expected.

```
  @observable user: User | null;
```

When the phone number is updated (removed) with `user.unlink(fb.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)`, the UI rendering the phone number is not re-rendered. I'm using `mobx-react` to make the components observable.

Basically I would like to know if `mobx` is actually observing the `phoneNumber` property. Or how to make the property `observable`.

Thanks in advance.